# How to return GUID/ID from stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure. It should return GUID/ID, but after executing it is returning the value either 2 or -1. I want it to return the GUID/ID only. Please help me to solve this.

Here is the code

Stored procedure:

```
create procedure SampleAddUser1
    (@Name nvarchar(MAX),
     @MailID nvarchar(MAX),
     @MobileNumber varchar(12),
     @Password nvarchar(MAX),
     @OTPNo varchar(10),
     @OTPExp datetime,
     @UserID uniqueidentifier output)
as
    if (not exists (select * from tbl_UserDetails where MobileNumber=@MobileNumber))
    begin
        begin transaction
            set @UserID = NEWID()

            insert into tbl_UserDetails(UserID, Name, Password, MobileNumber, MailID)
            values (@UserID, @Name, @Password, @MobileNumber, @MailID)

            insert into tbl_OTPDetails(UserId, OTPNo, OTPExp)
            values (@UserID, @OTPNo, @OTPExp)

            commit transaction
end
```

C# code is here.....

```
SqlParameter sqlParam = new SqlParameter("@UserID", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier);
sqlParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
param[6] = sqlParam;

r = _obj.ExecuteNonquery("SampleAddUser1", CommandType.StoredProcedure, param.ToArray());
```

`Obj.ExecuteNonQuery`:

```
   public int ExecuteNonquery(string commandText, 
   CommandType commandType, SqlParameter[] parameters)
    {
        try
        {
            cmd = new SqlCommand(commandText,con);
            cmd.CommandType = commandType;

            foreach (SqlParameter p in parameters)
            {
                if (p.Value == null)
                {
                }
                cmd.Parameters.Add(p);
            }
            int output= cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            return output;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: could you pls specify how you populate the rest of parameters in `param[]` list?

Comment: Thank you for replay. @andrews... here is the param[]

 SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[7];
  param[0] = new SqlParameter("@Name", objBAL.Name);
  param[1] = new SqlParameter("@Password", objBAL.Password);
  param[2] = new SqlParameter("@MailID", objBAL.MailId);
  param[3] = new SqlParameter("@MobileNumber", objBAL.MobileNumber);
  param[4] = new SqlParameter("@OTPNo", objOTP.OTPN0);
  param[5] = new SqlParameter("@OTPExp",objOTP.OTPExp);

Comment: and how do you try to read back `@UserID` param after `ExecuteNonquery` call finishes? Please, add all code to the question text, not comments.

Comment: its three tier architecture. Now you can see it in question text..

Comment: I asked how did you check the value returned in @UserID param AFTER your custom ExecuteNonquery finishes, you said it was either 2 or -1. Are you checking the `r` variable as in `r = _obj.ExecuteNonquery(...)`? If yes, of course you will not get Guid there because your `ExecuteNonquery` returns `int output= cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`

Comment: its working fine by adding this code line...

 Guid userId = (Guid)sqlParam.Value;

Thank you..

Comment: Please tell me con really isn't a global variable...  The connection instantiation should be in your method, wrapped in a using clause.  the SqlCommand should also be wrapped in a using clause.   You have a very high likelihood of having memory leak issues and other very hard to track down failures.  You really should put your code up on the code review site.  there's a LOT wrong with it.

Comment: A SQL Server stored procedure can **only** return `INT` (or `BIGINT`) values - typically it's used to indicate the number of rows affected (by an insert, update, delete operation), or to signal back an error condition. You ***cannot*** return a GUID or string using the `RETURN` statement from within a stored procedure. You have to send those back via an `OUTPUT` parameter, or via a result set (a `SELECT` statement)

Answer (score 3):

Should be pretty straightforward to get the `.Value` property of the output parameter:

```
SqlParameter sqlParam = new SqlParameter("@UserID", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier);
sqlParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
param[6] = sqlParam;
r = _obj.ExecuteNonquery("SampleAddUser1", CommandType.StoredProcedure, param.ToArray());

// get the returned parameter
Guid? userId = sqlParam.Value as Guid?;
```

One thing I noticed about your stored procedure is that a `NEWID()` is not guaranteed to be generated (in the case where there already exists a record with the same `@MobileNumber` in the database).  In which case, better be safe and use `Guid?` as the return type.

Comment: Doesn't work. Returns null no matter what I do. Even if I explicitly set the return output parameter to a value.

Answer (score 2):

You can't get a return value or output parameter from the return value of `ExecuteNonQuery()`. That will only return the row(s) affected.

To get the value of an output parameter:

```
var conn = new SqlConnection("my connection string");
var cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "dbo.MyProc";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

var sqlParam = new SqlParameter("@UserID",
SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier);
sqlParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output; 

cmd.Parameters.Add(sqlParam);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
// you can now access your output param
return (Guid)sqlParam.Value;
```

Comment: the OP doesn't use `ExecuteScalar()`, he uses `ExecuteNonQuery()`.

Comment: typo.. my answer still applies

Comment: Plus one for explaining the return value of `ExecuteNonQuery`. May want to add that if `set nocount` is `on`, the value will  be `-1`

Comment: Doesn't work. Returns null no matter what I do. Even if I explicitly set the return output parameter to a value.